# Hide extra relations that are loaded in an accessor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm loading relations inside an accessor attribute:

```
public function getNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->someRelation->name . ' x ' . $this->otherRelation->name;
}
```

When `->toJson` is called when sending data via Http response, the data from these relationships are included, but I only want to include the `name` attribute.

One solution could be just setting these relationships to `hidden`, but I'm reluctant to because I worry that will come back to bite me if I need to actually load those relationships.

How can I avoid this "side effect" data when converting my models to an array/json?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried, but from the [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json) you can use makeHidden() to *temporary* hide attributes (relations included), i.e.;

```
return $model->makeHidden(['someRelation', 'otherRelation'])->toJson();
// or
return $model->makeHidden('someRelation')->makeHidden('otherRelation')->toJson();
```

Comment: Seems to work for relations, but not for nested relations (someRelation.otherRelation)